# Encrypt a blob before the upload in Google Blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, webapp2

Is there any way to encrypt a file before, in the server side, before it is uploaded in the blobstore? This is apparently not possible via the upload handlers which are invoked after the actual upload.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a way for the file to be encrypted before it's uploaded, however, have you tried manipulating it once it has been uploaded and then reuploading, deleting the first file and using the original key for the newest uploaded blob?

Also take a look at Nicks comment - [How to manipulate files in google app engine datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224618/how-to-manipulate-files-in-google-app-engine-datastore#comment7264990_6231895)

Comment: I think I will go like this: Instead of using the upload url I am going to post the file to one of my handlers (via https). The handler will encrypt the file and through httplib post the encrypted file to a fresh the blobstore upload url.